# Sitecore XMCloud deploy

Tags: sitecore

I am trying to deploy to my XM Cloud instance using this command.

`dotnet sitecore cloud deployment create --environment-id <environmentId> --no-start --no-watch --upload --working-dir`

However, I get this error:

> Uploading source code is not permitted. The environment is already
> linked to a branch.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the link to my branch. Here is how I did it
In the XMC deployment dashboard, go to Projects>Your Project>Your branch>Options>Edit environment details
In the Link to branch dropdown, select None. Save. That's it!

[image]